# is there any possibility to check the button sizes and images are loading or not in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium2

how can I check frontend button sizes, logos, and images are loading or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the CSS values associated with an element.

[image]

```
driver.findElement(By.id(ID)).getCssValue("height");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check size of an element with:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".example css[selector]")).getSize();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can check if the element is visible on DOM or not by `explicit wait.(wait untill visibility of element)` and for size i think you should to get size of that webelement by `cssvalue`!